# Is there a Java equivalent for Ruby on Rails "url_for"?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, jsp

I have written something like this pretty easily in C# (`string GetUrl(new { controller = "foo", action = "bar", baz = "fnord" }`), based on the existing capabilities of the XmlRouteCollection class provided by the ASP.NET MVC framework (why it isn't there out of the box is beyond me; the additional required code was trivial). I am now faced with a JSP project, and I need the same ability: centralize the logic for generating all URLs in one place, based on a list of routing rules. Is there some code somewhere I could reuse/adapt to do this in Java? It seems like a common enough requirement, but google proved surprisingly unhelpful in finding something like this.

Comment: 1) Give us code sample so that we can understand what you're saying. 2) Edit your page, we can't see code sample (in C#) properly.

Comment: JSP is normally only used as the view layer. Are you using a web application framework, and if so, which one?

Comment: What I need is basically two functions: RegisterRoute(Dictionary parameterNamesAndValues, string urlTemplate); and GetUrl(Dictionary parameterNamesAndValues). For example RegisterRoute({ controller : 'foo', action : 'bar' }, "http://domain.name/some/path/{action}/{baz}.png") and then GetUrl({ controller : 'foo', action : 'bar', baz : 'fnord' }) will return "http://domain.name/some/path/bar/fnord.png"). The C# code isn't very interesting. As for a web framework, the project is married to a commercial closed-source E-commerce Web framework that doesn't provide the above. Time to code, I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw JSP doesn't provide such functionality. There a two choice:

1. use an exists framework that supports this (like a [grails](http://grails.org) or [play](http://www.playframework.org)),
2. or implement it by yourself, but it's no so easy, just because you need to implement also all other parts of RoR for this.

Comment: I'm forced to use a particular framework so using something like grails or play won't work :-( I guess I'll have to implement it myself...

Comment: oh, it's really hard to implement, i'd tried some times ago :(

Answer (score 0):

JSP is just a Java based view technology, it is not a MVC framework, you can best compare JSP with "Classic ASP". The Java EE counterpart of ASP.NET-MVC is JSF (JavaServer Faces). I know JSF thoroughly, but I don't seem to recognize the part what you need. It seems more to be RESTFul-flavored. In that case, have a look to [Spring 3.0 MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html). It provides ["URI-template" annotations](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/) to **listen** on certain RESTFul requests. True, this is also not really what you're looking for, but it might give you some new insights and ideas.

Comment: Spring URI templates are almost exactly what I need, except that they work in the wrong direction. They parse a URL and match it with an action; I need to specify an action and generate a URL. At any rate, this is academic; I can't use Spring, I'm stuck with a commercial framework (that has many other things, but not this).